# How to define a constant in C++?

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, mingw

I complied a linux program on windows via Mingw. However, the conversion was not perfect.
For example, on Windows the output is this (I get 'zu' instead of real numbers):

```
Approximated minimal memory consumption:
Sequence        : zuM
Buffer          : 1 X zuM = zuM
Table           : 1 X zuM = zuM
Miscellaneous   : zuM
Total           : zuM
```

It turns out that Mingw does not support %zu but it offers an workaround. On their [web site](http://sourceforge.net/p/mingw-w64/bugs/377/) they say:

> This will never work since you are using Microsoft's implementation.
>   Use mingw_printf directly or define USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO to 1 before
>   including stdio.h.

So, I did a search in my program and I have found that cdhit-common.h is the only file that has a #include line. So, I defined the USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO above that line and compiled:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<iomanip>
#include<cstdlib>
#define USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO 1
#include<stdio.h>
...
```

It compiles but the program still outputs 'zu' instead of numbers. Is it ok what I have done? Why didn't worked?

Note: The solution with USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO is for mingw64 while I use mingw. I hope is for both platforms.

Comment: I guess `<iostream>` includes `<stdio.h>` before you do, move `#define USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO 1` before `<iostream>`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The macros that I managed to google right now is:  `__USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO`. Try it.

Comment: Yes, looking at the HTML source shows that the SourceForge bug page linked to in the OP should say _"Use `__mingw_printf` directly or define `__USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO` to 1 before including stdio.h."_ but the `__` characters get converted to `<strong>` markup and are not visible

Comment: Jesus! This is how you waste 1 day for a 'minor' HTML bug! Good catch Jonathan & Predator!

Answer (score 2):

You are setting a pre-processor flag. That means that when the compiler reads `<stdio.h>` it will have `USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO` set to 1. This would potentially used in a compiler directive `#if` or `#ifdef`.

It is generally preferable to put these flags into your compile flags e.g.

`-DUSE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO=1` rather than into the code.

*( Note: it appears it might be `-D__USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO=1` )*

If you do put it into the code, do so either

- In a header that is always included before anything else, e.g. some "platform related" header.
- Before any other includes in your file.

It is possible that one of the C++ streaming headers implements using `<stdio.h>`

Comment: I changed the file. Do I have to do something else (delete some intermediary compiled/binary files generated by compiler) or is enough to just 'make'?

Comment: If you change your makefile cpp flags it should remake all your targets but is worth a make clean first just to be safe.