# C++0x printf() printing wrong value for double

Tags: c++, c++11, printf, double

Today I was trying to print a `double` value with `printf` function using `%lf` specifier but I got `0.000000`. But when I tried to print the same thing with `%f` specifier I got correct output. Why this happened? I use **c++0x**(**c++11** I think.)

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    double aaa;
    aaa=1.23;
    printf("%lf\n",aaa);
    printf("%f\n",aaa);
    return 0;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Seems to work: http://ideone.com/Fn7Wzm with a C compiler, http://ideone.com/RomBDW with a C++ compiler.

Comment: my compiler is compiling it with c++ @harald

Comment: @harald: Which part is not C++?

Comment: You sure you're not using C89? It was undefined behavior for printf(), specifically in C89, but commonly `%lf` was treated as `%f`. Commonly does not mean always, however.

Comment: @Zéychin I think I am not using C89. Anyway how can I check which compiler is running in codeblocks 10.05?

Comment: I used %lf for printing double with printf() before. But I recently started using c++0x and problem happening after that.

Comment: and I am unfamiliar with Codeblocks, maybe someone else has some input on this.

Comment: Other than you potentially using the wrong C/C++ standard, my thought is that the compiler is not 100% C++0x/C++11 compliant (Last I checked, no compiler is absolutely 100% compliant yet, but I am not primarily a C++ developer, so I have not checked in some time, so do not quote me on this).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Correct format specifier for double in printf](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4264127/correct-format-specifier-for-double-in-printf)

Comment: disagree that it's a duplicate of that

Comment: @madMDT your best option is probably to install a more recent compiler.  There is also a more recent version of Code::Blocks available. Whatever one you have now is bugged.

Comment: also see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25684134/1505939) although you should upgrade anyway

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this answer isn't totally correct, but according to [this reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/), it looks like `%l` is a length specifier for `long int` and `%f` is the specifier for `float`. Perhaps in the past this worked to print floating point variables, but I would guess that your code is attempting to treat the double variable `aaa` as a `long int`, and printing 0 as a result.

Comment: I suspect OP is linking against the Windows C library, which has a non-standard (in C99, compliant in C89) `printf` implementation. `%lf` expects a `long double` value there. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tcxf1dw6.aspx .

Comment: The reference you linked to is wrong.  That site contains a lot of mistakes. `%lf` is correct for printing `float` or `double`.

Comment: @M.M, thanks for letting me know. What references do you use for C++ documentation?

Comment: A [C++ standard draft](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/81656/where-do-i-find-the-current-c-or-c-standard-documents), or http://www.cppreference.com/

Answer (score 1):

From C99:

> The conversion specifiers and their meanings are:
>
> f,F - A double argument representing a floating-point number

.

> The length modifiers and their meanings are:
>
> l (ell) - ... has no effect on a following a, A, e, E, f, F, g, or G conversion
> specifier.

So effect must be the same for both calls. (Compiler bug? Old compiler?)

Comment: He's using the Visual Studio compiler in C++ mode; according to MSDN %lf means "long double": http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35208327/c0x-printf-printing-wrong-value-for-double

Comment: @kfsone The C++ standard specifies that functions from the C library behave the same in C++ as they would in ISO C99  , unless otherwise noted (and there are no other notes about the printf family)

Comment: @M.M Exactly. Thank you